# ggplot(data=mpg) but did not receive output

Tags: ggplot2, output

I ran this code:  ggplot(data=mpg) but did not receive output

I have installed the "tidyverse" packages which contains "ggplot2" function. I have also loaded the package during this session. I expected to see the mpg data displayed in the environment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? To get more useful and more specific help, better specify your question and goal.

- If you want to have `mpg` loaded into your global environment, you need to copy it from the package environment to the global environment with `mpg <- mpg`, although doing this can be redundant.
- If you want to draw a plot of the mpg data using ggplot, just calling `ggplot()` isn't enough. `ggplot(data = mpg)` initiates a plot, but needs mapping (e.g., `aes(x = hwy, y = cty)`. Additionally, to actually draw anything, you need to supply geometries, e.g., `geom_point()` for points and `geom_line()` for lines. Then you could get:

  ```
  # Initiate plot
  ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cty)) + 
      # Geometries
      geom_point() + geom_line()
  ```

  which gives:[image]
- If you just want an overview of the data, you can either use `view(mpg)` or print it in the console by running `mpg`.